# Why are many methods greyed out in the Android javadoc online?

Tags: android, javadoc

Apologies if this is a really stupid question, but when I look at the online android javadoc, for example https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack , a lot of the methods are greyed out. What is the significance of this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing

Answer (score 2):

Ah never mind, answered it. In the sidebar to the left, if you scroll all the way to the top, you can select which api version you are interested in. This affects the greyed out methods, such that methods not available yet to your api version are greyed out. Would be nice if it said at the top of each class as well what api version it was filtering for, as a reminder, but at least I know now.

[image]